# How to generate NES like noise for openAL?

Tags: noise, openal

As far as I remember the NES has 16 predefined noise samples. But I guess there might be some kind of logic behind the samples so that it could be generated with a fitting code.

So far I tried white and pink noise, but what I hear reminds me more of a rusty horn than static. What I'm looking for is something like the sound in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOFSrgwiG8k